# Automatic notes in Google Sheets drop down menu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet. In 'Main' worksheet I have a drop down list in Column A. The information in this drop down is being pulled from Column A of 'Places' worksheet.

For purposes of space saving on the 'Main' worksheet I am reducing the place names down to 2 or 3 letter abbreviations so as an example Pontypandy would become PP. Is there any way that when I pick 'PP' in the drop down on the 'main' worksheet, there is an automatic note added to it which would read 'Pontypandy' and would be visible to anyone who hovered the cursor over that particular cell?

***Further Detail:***

Below is my most recent effort at the script that you have kindly helped with to include the recent modifications you gave me which are in lines 3 and 4. Please don't be alarmed by the difference in sheet names, I have now moved onto my actual spreadsheet having been working in a test environment previously so I am now using the correct sheet names as detailed in the script below.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheetNames = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08",,,];
      if (sheetNames.some(s => range.getSheet().getsheetName() == s) && range.columnStart == 5) {
  const object = {
      AVD: "AV Dawson Middlesbrough",
      BA: "Basford Hall, Crewe (FLR)",
      BH: "Barrow Hill Roundhouse",
      BKR: "Bo'ness & Kinneil Railway",
      BN: "Bounds Green (LNER)",
      CD: "Crewe Diesel (Locomotive Storage Ltd)",
      CE: "Crewe Electric TMD",
      CF: "Cardiff Canton",
      CFT: "Cardiff Tidal",
      ChaR: "Chasewater Railway",
      CPRR: "Chinoor & Princes Risborough Railway",
      CZ: "Central Rivers (Bombardier)",
      DRM: "Doncaster Royal Mail Terminal",
      EH: "Eastleigh (Arriva Traincare)",
      EHY: "Eastleigh East Yard",
      ELY: "Ely Papworth Sidings",
      EML: "EMD Longport",
      FX: "Felixstowe Docks",
      HT: "Heaton, Newcastle",
      IL: "Ilford (Greater Anglia)",
      LA: "Laira (Great Western)",
      LB: "Loughborough Brush Traction",
      LD: "Leeds Midland Road (FLR)",
      LE: "Landore (Great Western)",
      LM: "Long Marston",
      LR: "Leicester L.I.P (UKRL)",
      NA: "Newton Aycliffe (Hitachi)",
      NC: "Norwich Crown Point",
      PG: "Peterborough (GBRf)",
      PM: "Bristol St Phillips Marsh",
      RR: "Roberts Road, Doncaster",
      SZ: "Southampton Maritime (FLR)",
      TO: "Toton (DBC)",
      TY: "Tyne Yard",
      WB: "Wembley (Alstom)",
      WEN: "Wensleydale Railway",
      WI: "Wishaw",
      ZB: "Doncaster Wabtec",
  };
   const v = range.getValue();
      range.setNote(v in object ? object[v] : "");
    }     

}
```

My requirement has not changed. I still require that when I pick a selection from the dropdown list in `column E` that a note appears with further detail relating to the selection I have made, as per the list of objects in the script above. So for a couple of examples if I select "AVD" from the dropdown, I require a note to appear stating "AV Dawson Middlesbrough" and if I select "BA" I require a note to appear stating "Basford Hall, Crewe (FLR)".

This worked fine when we were trialling it in just one worksheet but I am struggling to get the above script to work, to get this to work across all worksheets, as I receive the following error message when I try to save it in it's current form:

> Syntax error. (line 4, file "Depot Notes")Dismiss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Question 1:

- There is the drop down list at the column "A" in the sheet of `Main`.
- When the drop down list is changed, you want to add a note to the active drop down list.
- For example, when the drop down list is changed to `PP`, you want to add `Pontypandy` corresponding to `PP` to the cell of the drop down list.

In this answer, I would like to propose to use Google Apps Script and the OnEdit event trigger of the simple trigger. The conversion from `PP` to `Pontypandy` is run by using the object.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the container-bound script of the Google Spreadsheet and save it. When you change the drop down list at the column "A" in the sheet of `Main` to `PP`, the script is run by the OnEdit event trigger, and  you can see the value of `Pontypandy` as the note.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  if (range.getSheet().getSheetName() == "Main" && range.columnStart == 1) {
    const object = {  // Please set the following object.
      PP: "Pontypandy",
      key1: "value1",
      key2: "value2",
    };
    const v = range.getValue();
    range.setNote(v in object ? object[v] : "no value");
  }
}
```

- In this sample script, when the value of drop down list is not included in `object`, `no value` is put to the note. About this, please modify it for your actual situation.

#### Note:

- From your question,

  - I couldn't understand about the information of the rows of the column "A" in the sheet `Main`. So in this sample script, the row number is not used. So please be careful this. If you want to include the information of row, please reflect it.
  - I couldn't understand about the information of the column "A" of the sheet of 'Places'. So in this sample, an object which was manually created was used.
- **When you directly run the function of `onEdit` at the script editor, an error occurs. So please be careful this.**

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [setNote(note)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotenote)

## Question 2:

- You want to run the script with the several sheet names.
- You want to run the script when the drop down list at the column "E" is changed.

  - In your question, from `In 'Main' worksheet I have a drop down list in Column A.`, I checked the column "A". But from your replying, this modification is also reflected.

In this case, please modify above script as follows.

### Modified script:

#### From:

```
if (range.getSheet().getSheetName() == "Main" && range.columnStart == 1) {
```

#### To:

```
const sheetNames = ["Main", "Sheet1", "Sheet2",,,];
if (sheetNames.some(s => range.getSheet().getSheetName() == s) && range.columnStart == 5) {
```

- Please set the sheet names to the array of `sheetNames`.
- By above modification, when the drop down list at the column "E" on the sheet names of `sheetNames` is changed, the script is run.

Comment: Works a treat, thank you very much. Just one further thing - I have multiple worksheets that I actually require this script to work on. I have made that work by adding to the ```if``` line of your script in this manner.....```if (range.getSheet().getSheetName() == "Main" || range.getSheet().getSheetName() == "Backup"  && range.columnStart == 5) {``` ...I have many more worksheets to include so is there a shorter way of doing this and is there a limit to how many sheets can be allocated to a particular script?

Comment: Also, just to tidy things up slightly, where I have used ```range.columnStart == 5``` as in the above comment, it is actually only column 5 of each worksheet that this relates to (each worksheet I have are setup the same) so do I need to use columnStart or can I simply use ```range.column``` (if this exists) to ensure the script only relates to column 5 and no other column?

Comment: @The_Train Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I added one more modified script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for your modified response. I have a couple of things to clarify - 1) ```if (sheetNames.some(s => range.getSheet().getSheetName() == s) && range.columnStart == 5) {``` - on this line I am receiving a Syntax Error message and no matter how much I try to change things slightly, the error message remains

Comment: And 2) where you have put "Please set the sheet names to the array of sheetNames." in your bullet points, are we talking about me adding the following code: ```function sheetNames() {
  var out = new Array()
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
  return out 
}```

Comment: @The_Train Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot understand about your current situation of your new question. So can you provide your current whole script for replicating your issue and the detail explanation of the issue? If you can do, please add them to your question. Because it is difficult to see the script in the comment. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad.

Comment: There is absolutely no inconvenience (except maybe from me to you) and I am extremely thankful for your help and your continued support. I have added further detail to my original question under "Further Details" and hopefully this will be clearer for you (I didn't realise I could edit my original question so I have learnt something there). I try to solve problems myself prior to seeking help but having spent hours without a positive result, I need to turn to your expertise once again to help me and also teach me - thank you once again!

Comment: @The_Train Thank you for replying updating it. When I saw your script, I noticed that a spell miss. Please modify `getsheetName()` to `getSheetName()` in the if statement, and test it again. And also, please confirm whether V8 runtime is enabled at the script editor.

Comment: that spell error was indeed the Syntax Error that I couldn't see previously and the correction of that has fixed the issue and my spreadsheet is working as desired with regards to the notes. Thanks very much for all of your help with this matter. As for your final question, V8 runtime wasn't enabled but I have now enabled it - do I need to do anything further with that?

Comment: I also wish to now expand your fantastic script to have the same effect on other columns which carry different information. I have tried to do this by copying the same script but changing the objects to the different information and also changing the columnStart to 2 (as I require it to relate to the ```B``` column. This has worked in the ```B``` column but is now stopping the previous script in column 5 from working - can I make it so I can have this working in multiple columns?

Comment: @The_Train Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about your new question. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. And also, your new question is different from your initial question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? By this, I would like to confirm it and think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Thanks for your response, and no problem of the understanding of my new question - I should have started brand new to help with the understanding instead of using the comments. I have now set a brand new question as per your request